# Can I interpret Deviance as a sort of distance?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, generalized-linear-model, distance, deviance

I've been studying some GLM theory, and I ran into deviance recently.

Seems like the deviance has properties similar to a metric.  Namely:

- $ D(y, y)=0$
- Non-negativity $D(y, \mu) \geq 0$

I hesitate to add subadditivity to the list, but Deviance has something like it.

Furthermore, when we fit a GLM, we maximize the log liklihood function, which in turn should minimize the deviance, no?

So does deviance have an interpretation as a distance?

Comment: You cannot consider it a distance metric, as $D(y, x) \neq D(x, y)$.